# Destructuring: How can this even work?

Tags: clojure, destructuring

As an answer to a question on SO I was building a recurring function, and built my most complicated destructuring yet, which miraculously worked:

```
(defn fib?
  [a b & [c & r]]
  (if (= c (+ a b))
    (if r
      (recur b c r)
      true)
    false))

(fib? 0 1 1)
=> true

(fib? 2 3 5 8 13)
=> true
```

But I have no idea why it should work. The `r` used in the`recur` is a collection, something which would make the original function fail.

```
(fib? 2 3 [5 8 13])
=> false
```

I wanted to use something like `apply recur` there, but since `recur` is a special form, that's not possible. So I tried without it and it worked. Does `recur` have magical auto-apply properties or is there something else I'm not seeing.

Comment: Perhaps the logic of your function is clearer if you write the body thus: `(and (= c (+ a b)) (or (not r) (recur b c r)))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The are two parts to the answer:

1. The "rest" parameter of a variadic function becomes the final parameter in any `recur` forms that recur to the top of the function. At this point it is no longer special in any way. You'll normally want to ensure that any values passed in that position actually are sequential, but even this is not enforced.<sup>1</sup>
2. Destructuring is just syntactic sugar provided by the `fn` and `let` macros. The desugared version of an `fn` form that uses destructuring in its parameter vector takes a certain number of regular arguments, then destructures them in a `let` form wrapping the entire body. Thus if you recur to the top of a function that uses destructuring in its parameter vector, the new values will be destructured for the next iteration.

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, `((fn [& xs] (if (seq? xs) (recur (first xs)) xs)) 1 2 3)` returns `1`.